# Webpack/Angular CLI: auto reload + local network access not working together

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

If I run this:

> ng serve --open

Auto-refresh works, but I can't access the site from my phone

If I run this:

> ng serve --open --host 0.0.0.0 --public 192.168.1.139:8080

I can access the site from 192.168.1.139:4200 (no idea, why that port works and 8080 doesn't), but on my desktop, the auto-refresh after doing changes doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, but it is a bit too hacky. Here's how to run Angular CLI in local area network and how to access it from your phone.

I basically run 2 separate servers, but I run one server in different port.

In Windows I open 2 command prompts (as admin) and in the first I run this:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --public 192.168.1.139:8080
```

192.168.1.139 is my PC's IP, even though I the command on port 8080, on my phone I can access the project from 192.168.1.139:4200 (4200 is the default Angular CLI port I guess).

On the second command prompt I run:

```
ng serve --open --port 4201
```

This opens a browser window that refreshes automatically in your desktop.